# c++ porgram wont run is there an error with my constructor

Tags: c++

Constructor

This class has one constructor that should initialize the data member using the passed in arguments. It takes 5 arguments: a character array that holds the student's name, an integer that holds the number of program points the student has earned, an integer that holds the number of quiz points the student has earned, an integer that holds the sum of the student's two lowest quiz scores, and a double that holds the number of exam points that the student has earned.

The name data member should be initialized using the passed in argument and the strcpy function. The remaining numeric arguments should be initialized by calling the appropriate set access method and passing in the appropriate argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;
class Student
{
    public:
    Student(char[],int,int,int,double);




     void setPgmPts( int newPgmPts );
     void setQuizPts( int newQuizPts );
     void setSum2Low( int newSum2Low );
     void setExamPts( double newExamPts);
     double calcPgmAverage();
     double calcExamAndQuizAverage();
     double calcCourseAverage();
     char letterGrade();
     void printStudent();

private:
    char studentName[50];
    int studentProg,studentQuiz,studentLowestQ;
    double studentExam;
    static const int MAX_Pgm_Pts;
    static const int MAX_Quiz_Pts;
    static const int sumLowestQ;
    static const double MAX_Exam_Pts;
        }; 


    const int Student::MAX_Pgm_Pts = 905;
const int Student::MAX_Quiz_Pts = 120;
const int Student::sumLowestQ = 20;
const double Student::MAX_Exam_Pts = 300;   


int main()
{


Student student1("Ryan Manion",767,106,10,286.50);
Student student2("Peter Laviolette",474,53,0,218.50);
Student student3("Joel Quenneville",905,120,20,300.00);
Student student4("invalid invalid",-1,-2,-3,-4.00);

cout << "The first Student object" << endl; 
student1.printStudent();


cout << "The second Student object" << endl; 
student2.printStudent();

cout << "The Third Student object" << endl; 
student3.printStudent();

cout << "The fourth Student object" << endl;
student4.printStudent();



}


//Code the constructors and methods for the Coin class after this line

/***************************************************************
method: void setPgmPts( int newPgmPts )

Use:makes a change to the data member that holds the number of 
program points that the student has earned. 

Arguments:It takes 1 argument: an integer that holds a new 
number of program points.

Returns: nothing
***************************************************************/

 void Student::setPgmPts( int newPgmPts )

    {

    if (newPgmPts < 0 && newPgmPts > MAX_Pgm_Pts)
        {
         cout <<"Error in setPgmPts: argument is invalid";
         studentProg = 0;

        }

    else 
        {
        studentProg = newPgmPts;

        }
    }


/***************************************************************
method:void setQuizPts( int newQuizPts )

Use: makes a change to the data member that holds the number 
of quiz points that the student has earned.

Arguments:It takes 1 argument: an integer that holds a new 
number of quiz points.

Returns:nothing
***************************************************************/

 void Student::setQuizPts( int newQuizPts )

    {
        if (newQuizPts < 0 && newQuizPts > MAX_Quiz_Pts)
        {
         cout <<"Error in setQuizPts: argument is invalid";
         studentQuiz = 0;

        }

    else 
        {
        studentQuiz = newQuizPts;

        }


    }


/***************************************************************
void setSum2Low( int newSum2Low )

Use: makes a change to the data member that holds the sum of 
the two lowest quiz scores earned by the student.

Arguments:It takes 1 argument: an integer that holds a new 
sum of the two lowest quiz scores.

Returns:nothing
***************************************************************/


 void Student::setSum2Low( int newSum2Low )

    {

        if (newSum2Low < 0 && newSum2Low > sumLowestQ)
        {
         cout <<"Error in setSum2Low: argument is invalid";
         studentLowestQ = 0;

        }

    else 
        {
        studentLowestQ = newSum2Low;

        }


    }

/***************************************************************
method:void setExamPts( double newExamPts )

Use:makes a change to the data member that holds the number 
of exam points that the student has earned.

Arguments:It takes 1 argument: a double that holds a new 
number of exam points.

Returns: nothing
***************************************************************/

void Student::setExamPts( double newExamPts )

    {

    if (newExamPts < 0 && newExamPts > MAX_Exam_Pts)
        {
         cout <<"Error in setExamPts: argument is invalid";
         studentExam = 0;

        }

    else 
        {
        studentExam = newExamPts;

        }

    }

/***************************************************************
method:double calcPgmAverage()

Use:returns the calculated program average for a student.

Arguments:none

Returns:a double, which is the calculated program average.
***************************************************************/

double Student::calcPgmAverage()

    {
    double pgmAverage;

    pgmAverage = studentProg / MAX_Pgm_Pts * 100;

    return pgmAverage;


    }

/***************************************************************
method:double calcExamAndQuizAverage()

Use:returns the calculated exam and quiz average for a student.

Arguments:none

Returns: a double, which is the calculated exam and quiz average.
***************************************************************/

double Student::calcExamAndQuizAverage()

    {
    double examAndQuizAverage;

    examAndQuizAverage = studentExam + studentQuiz - studentLowestQ / 

    MAX_Exam_Pts + MAX_Pgm_Pts - sumLowestQ * 100;

    }

/***************************************************************
method:double calcCourseAverage()

Use:returns the calculated course average for a student.

Arguments:none

Returns:  a double, which is the calculated course average.
***************************************************************/

double Student::calcCourseAverage()

    {

    double courseAverage;

    courseAverage = .35 * calcPgmAverage() + .65 * calcExamAndQuizAverage();

    return courseAverage;

    }

/***************************************************************
char letterGrade()

Use:will determine the student's letter grade for the course.

Arguments:none

Returns:a character: the student's letter grade.
***************************************************************/

char Student::letterGrade()

    {
    char letterGrade;

     if(calcCourseAverage() >= 90.00 && calcCourseAverage() <= 100.00)
        {

        letterGrade = 'A';

        }
     else if (calcCourseAverage() >= 0.00 && calcCourseAverage() <= 90.00)     
        {

        letterGrade = 'B';
        }
     else if (calcCourseAverage() >= 70.00 && calcCourseAverage() <= 80.00)
        {

        letterGrade = 'C';
        }
     else if (calcCourseAverage() >= 60.00 && calcCourseAverage() <= 70.00)
        {

        letterGrade = 'D';
        }
     else if (calcCourseAverage() < 60.00)
        {

        letterGrade = 'F';
        }
     else if (calcPgmAverage() < 55.00 && calcExamAndQuizAverage() < 55.00) 
        {

        letterGrade = 'F';
        }  

    return letterGrade;
    }

/***************************************************************
method:void printStudent()

Use: will display the student's course information.

Arguments:none

Returns:nothing
***************************************************************/
void Student::printStudent()

    {
    for (int i = 0; i <strlen(studentName); i++)
        {
        cout << studentName[i];

        }

    cout << setprecision(5)<<"Program Average:     " << calcPgmAverage();
    cout << setprecision(5)<< "Exam + Quiz Average:     " << calcExamAndQuizAverage();
    cout << setprecision(5)<<"Course Average:     " << calcCourseAverage();
    cout << setprecision(5)<< "Letter Grade:     " << letterGrade();

    }



Student::Student(char studentName[],int studentProg,int studentQuiz,int studentLowestQ,double studentExam)

    {

    strcpy(studentName,"Ryan Manion");
    setPgmPts(studentProg);
    setQuizPts(studentQuiz); // it has to match the setQuizPts declaration 
    setSum2Low(studentLowestQ); // same as above
    setExamPts(studentExam); // same as above

    }
```

Comment: And what, exactly, is the error message you get from your compiler? Don't make us guess.

Comment: oh im sorry here it is  
MAX_Pgm_Pts was not declared in this scope
studentProg was not declared in this scope

Comment: and than no matching function for call to student::setQuizPts() 
no matching function for call toStudent::setSum2Low
no matching function for call to setExamPts()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the function setPgmPts, you forgot the class scope name, it should be:

```
void Student::setPgmPts( int newPgmPts )
```

Also, you defined these member functions must take an argument

```
 void setQuizPts( int newQuizPts );
 void setSum2Low( int newSum2Low );
 void setExamPts( double newExamPts);
```

And in your constructor, you're calling them without passing any argument.

```
studentQuiz = setQuizPts();
studentLowestQ = setSum2Low();
studentExam = setExamPts();
```

Also, your trying to obtain a return value from a void function, which doesn't make any sense.
You must call them following their definition, for example:

```
setQuizPts(1);
setSum2Low(2);
setExamPts(3.0);
```

Or whatever int/double you want to use.

Comment: still getting the no matching function for call to error in my constructor again thanks!

Comment: You need to pass an int as a parameter as your definition specifies.
You defined *void setQuizPts( int newQuizPts );*
And you're trying to call it without an int as parameter in the constructor 
*studentQuiz = setQuizPts();*

Comment: im sorry i dont think i undestand could you elaborate

Comment: like this?

        studentProg = setPgmPts(int newPgmPts);
  studentQuiz = setQuizPts(int newQuizPts);
  studentLowestQ = setSum2Low(int newSum2Low);
  studentExam = setExamPts( double newExamPts);

Comment: i did this  setPgmPts(studentProg);
  setQuizPts(studentQuiz);
  setSum2Low(studentLowestQ);
  setExamPts(studentExam);
 and now it compiles but it dosent display anything

Comment: You should really take a look at how contructors in C++ work, here's something http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Answer (score 0):

You have a function, `setPgmPts` declared outside the `Student` class. This function is attempting to access members of `Student` (`MAX_Pgm_Pts` and `studentProg`) but it doesn't have access to `Student` internals. You will need to make this a member of your `Student` class, or provide `public` access and a `Student` object to work with

Answer (score 0):

The code is broken on many levels.

```
//declarations; those functions take one int argument
void setPgmPts( int newPgmPts );
void setQuizPts( int newQuizPts ); 
void setSum2Low( int newSum2Low );
void setExamPts( double newExamPts);
```

The constructor would have to look something like this:

```
Student::Student(char studentName[],int studentProg,int studentQuiz,int studentLowestQ,double studentExam)

{

    strcpy(studentName,"Ryan Manion");
    //studentProg = calcPgmAverage();->invalid
    setQuizPts(studentQuiz); // it has to match the setQuizPts declaration 
    setSum2Low(studentLowestQ); // same as above
    setExamPts(studentExam); // same as above
}
```

Instead of

```
studentProg = calcPgmAverage();
```

you would like to use something like this:

```
Student student ( values for initialization);
double d = student.calcPgmAverage();
```

Comment: ok i think i fixed those but now it compiles but it does not display anything.